# Evenly distribute divs horizontally within floated(or inline-block) parent

Tags: html, css, flexbox, justify

I'm trying to horizontally distribute child items evenly within their parent. I'm aware of the `text-align:justify` and flex methods—I'm currently using the flex method.

The problem is that my layout(a logo[red] to the left that's `float:left` or `display:inline-block` and a button[black] that's to the right and `float:right`) requires that the flex parent div be `float:left` or `display:inline-block`(so that it sits between the logo and the button), but floating or displaying inline-block breaks the flex distribution I have applied for the kids.

Here's a CodePen of where I'm at so far: http://codepen.io/dmoz/pen/QKaQrL

This is an image of what I need:

[image: the goal]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated your CSS. Check the Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Lq89dwxL/

```
.header {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background: #f5f5f5;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 10px;
  overflow: auto;
}
.logo {
  width: 100px;
  height: 30px;
  margin: 8px 50px 10px 0;
  background: red;
}
button {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  margin: 8px 0 0 50px;
  border: none;
  background: black;
}
.item_container {
  width:100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 0 55px 0 15px;
}
.item {
  width:25px;
  height: 30px;
  background: blue;
  margin: 8px 5px;
}
```

Comment: Curious as to why you started adding (seemingly) random margins, as it throws the distribution off and makes the items uneven. I tweaked your JSFiddle here to (potentially) neaten it up to OP's request: https://jsfiddle.net/Lq89dwxL/1/

Comment: You may ignore the margins, it's up to you. The problem was in making them inline, and it's solved

Comment: I'm not OP - I am just a passerby. I just found it odd that you shrunk his logo and added uneven padding to either side. I just modified your example to keep the sizes as they were in OP's example, and made the margin on either side uniform. You solved the issue, I just modified it very slightly. Good job nonetheless.

Comment: @Santi, agreed. He sorta hacked up my original layout/dimensions, but the layout with the margins is essentially what needs to be there to accomplish it.